# Pandas Data Summarization

Tags: python-3.x, summarization

I have a fuzzy data, which is as below. Kindly note that the first item has repeating names(which is kind of important to consider).

```
('Alex', ['String1', 'String34'])
('Piper', ['String5', 'String64', 'String12'])
('Nicky', ['String3', 'String21', 'String42', 'String51'])
('Linda', ['String14'])
('Suzzane', ['String11', 'String36', 'String16'])
('Alex', ['String64', 'String34', 'String12', 'String5'])
('Linda', ['String3', 'String77'])
('Piper', ['String41', 'String64', 'String11', 'String34'])
('Suzzane', ['String12'])
('Nicky', ['String11',  'String51'])
('Alex', ['String77', 'String64', 'String3', 'String5'])
('Linda', ['String51'])
('Nicky', ['String77', 'String12', 'String34'])
('Suzzane', ['String51', 'String3'])
('Piper', ['String11', 'String64', 'String5'])
```

If the above data were in a file called "output.txt", how would one import it and summarize the data as shown below?

[Only unique names remain, and for each main name, only unique strings will be populated from all the duplicates that existed]

```
('Alex', ['String1', 'String34', 'String64', 'String12', 'String5', 'String77', 'String3'])
('Piper', ['String5', 'String64', 'String12', 'String11', 'String41', 'String34'])
('Nicky', ['String3', 'String21', 'String42', 'String51', 'String11', 'String77', 'String12', 'String34'])
('Linda', ['String14', 'String3', 'String77', 'String51'])
('Suzzane', ['String11', 'String36', 'String16', 'String12', 'String51', 'String3'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast
import csv
import pandas as pd

#load data from txt file, doesnt has to be csv, can be a txt file!
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\test\output.txt", sep="/n", header=None, names=["data"], engine='python')

#convert text data to tupels and list
df["data"] = df["data"].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
#extract surename
df["surename"] = df["data"].map(lambda x: x[0])
#extract list of strings
df["strings"] = df["data"].map(lambda x: x[1])
#create 1 row for each string in the list of strings
df = df.explode("strings")
#remove duplicate entries
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["surename", "strings"], keep="first")
#group the data by surename to get a list of unique strings (unique because we removed duplicates, order will be kept)
df_result = df.groupby(["surename"]).aggregate({"strings":list}).reset_index()
#combine both th extractd surename and the modified list of strings again
df_result["result"] = df_result.apply(lambda x: (x["surename"], x["strings"]), axis=1)

#output the data to a file of your choice
df_result[["result"]].to_csv(r"D:\test\result.txt",index=False, header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = '')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load the data into a pandas `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('Alex', ['String1', 'String34']),
('Alex', ['String64', 'String34', 'String12', 'String5']),
('Nicky', ['String11',  'String51']),
('Nicky', ['String77', 'String12', 'String34'])])
df = df.rename(columns={0:'name', 1:'strings'})
```

Then create a `function` to concatenate lists on a pandas column:

```
def concatenate(strings):
   strings_agg = []
    for string in strings:
        strings_agg.extend(string)
    return strings_agg
```

And finally `apply` the function to the column:

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: concatenate(x['strings'])).to_frame()
```

Comment: Dear @Franco Piccolo, thank you for your kind answer, and I have a small doubt here. What if the data is in a file like "Output.txt" Should I change the extension to ".csv" and import the dataframe please?

Comment: Yes you could load the data from a csv. I don't think it will be that straightforward though, because the list will be read as text. Maybe you should ask another question for the import part.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that pandas is a *great* library, but this kinds of things can be done very easily with plain python builtin packages<sup>1</sup>. You can simply use python [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with sets, and use regex [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) for parsing.

<sup><sup>1</sup>*Make sense especially since neither your input nor output is in any of the pandas datatypes* (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame,..) or even a standard .csv / tabular format..</sup>

#### Code

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

dataset = defaultdict(set)

with open('output.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        itr = re.finditer("'(\S+?)'", line)
        name = next(itr).groups()[0]
        strings = {x.groups()[0] for x in itr}
        dataset[name] |= strings

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name, strings in dataset.items():
        print(f"('{name}', {list(strings)})", file=f)
```

#### Example output

```
('Alex', ['String1', 'String5', 'String77', 'String64', 'String34', 'String12', 'String3'])
('Piper', ['String5', 'String11', 'String64', 'String34', 'String12', 'String41'])
('Nicky', ['String21', 'String77', 'String34', 'String11', 'String51', 'String3', 'String12', 'String42'])
('Linda', ['String77', 'String14', 'String51', 'String3'])
('Suzzane', ['String11', 'String36', 'String12', 'String16', 'String51', 'String3'])
```

#### Explaining how the code works

- Read line by line. We can use regular expression that catches anything which is non-whitespace (`\S`) between two single quotes (`'`). Therefore, the regex pattern is `'(\S+?)'`. The plus `+` means that match one or more characters and `?` makes the search non-greedy (match as few characters as possible), so we get all the separate strings parsed, not just one string with all the content from the row.
- The [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) is used to match multiple groups with the same pattern. In this case, it is used instead of `re.findall` since `re.findall` creates a *list* and `re.finditer` creates an *iterator*. (small optimization: do not create list because it is not needed at all)
- Then, we capture the `name` by calling [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the `itr`. It returns the first element from the iterator.
- Then, call the [`groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) and take the first item from the returned value. This is how the groups captured with parenthesis (`()`) in the pattern are accessed.
- Then, for the rest of the iterator `itr` we have only strings from which we want to create python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which quarantee unique elements. The syntax shown is the *set comprehension*.
- On the same line we save the resulting set into the `dataset` variable, which is a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). defaultdicts are nice since when accessing to non-existing item, it automatically creates an entry with that type. We have used `defaultdict(set)` to have `set` as default type. The operation `d[key] |= val` is same thing as `d[key] = d[key] | val`, and the [`|`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) creates set that is the *union* of the new set and the set we might already have in the `dataset`.
- The last part just writes the output line-by-line to `results.txt`. Casting the `strings` to list is optional, but it is made to make the output similar to what was in the question.

Comment: Woww.. Thanks @np8.. I would have taken a while to figure it out, as the code is so clean, compared to mine.. but your explanation really helps.. much appreciated... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = []
a_dict = {}
unique = []

#considering that the file name is a.txt here.
#After opening the file i used the eval function to turn the string into code
#now the list data will have all the file's data, all elements inside list data are tuples
with open('a.txt','r') as file:
    for i in file.readlines():
        a = eval(i)
        data.append(a)

#here i wrote this code for collecting all unique name in a list
for i in data:
    if i[0] not in unique:
        unique.append(i[0])


#after collecting unique names inside list unique, i performed iteration over all values inside list unique.
#
#then i performed iteration on the list which is holding all the data
#
#compared all the unique values with the list data and
#then if they are matching then adding those values inside a list a_list
#
#when it is finished with the iteration inside list data, it will add that list into a dict a_dict with its unique value
#
#a_list will be assigned a new list for the next unique value
for i in unique:
    a_list = []
    for j in data:
        if i==j[0]:
            a_list.extend(j[1])
    a_dict[i] = list(tuple(a_list))
    
#This piece of code is to print out the data in a formatted way.
for i,j in a_dict.items():
    print("('{}', {})".format(i,j))
```